# opencv 3.0 linker issue with vs 2012

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I am having an issue with getting the opencv 3.0 library to be included in visual studio 2012. Here is the error I am getting:

```
    Build started: Project: PADVisionEngine, configuration: Debug x64
    1> LINK: fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'Libjasper.dll'
```

I added these things in the project configuration:

```
    Executable Dir: C:\opencv_3.0.0\opencv\build\x64\vc11\bin;
    Include Dir: C:\opencv_3.0.0\opencv\build\include;
    Library Dir:
         C:\opencv_3.0.0\opencv\build\x64\vc11\lib;
         C:\opencv_3.0.0\opencv\build\x64\vc11\staticlib;
```

I also added all the .dll files in the "Additional Dependencies" in linker under input. What am I missing that is making me having this error?

Comment: You are supposed to add the `lib`s not the `dll`s to the linker input.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you are adding dlls to your `"Additional Dependencies" in linker under input` This is for libraries not dlls. In the case of dlls you use import libraries (which also have  `.lib` extension)